# I am using Firebase Apple sign-in for user login but I am not sure where do I put https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

I am using Firebase Apple sign-in-with-apple for user login but I am not sure where do I put  https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

This is documentation from Firebase login.
*To complete set up, add this authorization callback URL to your app configuration in the Apple Developer Console. Additional steps may be needed to verify ownership of this web domain to Apple. Learn more *  Learn more takes me here. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?authuser=0

Do I need to do this for mobile react native app?

Answer (score 7):

If you go to `Identifiers` in the Developer Center, you can click on your application and then select `Edit` for the **Sign In With Apple** capability and enter the Firebase callback URL

Comment: If anybody's looking for the link: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list

Comment: It is worth noting, your Service Id does not need to be the same as your app's bundle ID. You can do something like, "com.myTeam.MyApp.service", then tie that ID to the ID Group for your Entire app, for example, "group.myTeam.MyApp". 

Once that is complete you may enter your callback URLs accordance with the above instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't put it anywhere and it started working so I think for Android and iOS / Mobile Apple Login doesn't require you to do this portion.

Comment: It is required when you use Sign in with Apple on web or Android.

Comment: can you confirm that this is not required for ios?

Answer (score 0):

This is what seems to work for me:

1. Go to Apple Developer Center, select "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" -> "Identifiers".
2. Then in the right upper corned select "Services IDs"
3. If you don't have a service id, create one for Sign In with Apple. There you'll be able to enter your URL into the ""Website URLs/Return URL" field. Also during the setup you'll save your key that you should afterwards enter into your Firabase auth config for Sign in with Apple.
4. If you already have a service id for Sign in with Apple, click on it and then click "Configure" for "Sign In with Apple". There you'll see "Website URLs" and will be able to add a "Return URL".